# Where and when is this dragon watermark from?

Tags: book

I'm doing some historical research on a manuscript. I'm having trouble finding where this watermark is from however. [Watermark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cVRV.jpg):

I'm very sure the watermark is a dragon type watermark from a printer between 1400-1600. I've already consulted Briquet's 1907 work concerning watermarks, but couldn't find it there. I'm quite certain the watermark can be found in Gerhard Piccard's Wasserzeichen Fabeltiere - Greif Drache Einhorn. I don't have access to the work however.

I'd like to know which company produced this watermark, when and where if that's possible. Also the number in the work so I can cite it.

Comment: How do you know: "*I'm very sure the watermark is a dragon type watermark from a printer between 1400-1600*"?  Questions are expected to arrive with sufficient description that answerers need not repeat research already done by OP.

Comment: I think it's a pity this question was closed, for what strike me as formal reasons.  Especially when other recent questions, founded on strange speculative theories are not closed.

Answer (score 3):

A form of Piccard is online.  Typing "drache" in the search box on https://www.piccard-online.de/struktur.php gets 200-odd hits, some of which look like your image.   In particular, https://www.wasserzeichen-online.de/wzis/struktur.php?ref=IT6900-PO-123950  , whose metadata includes

> Wasserzeichen IT6900-PO-123950
> Referenznummer  IT6900-PO-123950  
> Motivgruppe Fabelwesen - Drache - frei, ganze Figur - ohne Beizeichen - waagrecht/steigend
> Quelle  Italien, Prato, Archivio di Stato, Prato, A Datini 855
> 1404, Brügge
> Sammlung    Piccard-Online
> Abmessungen || 59 mm, Breite 50 mm, Höhe 64 mm
> Bezüge  Piccard-Findbücher Online